# How to get the path name of an URL in view?

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-urls, django-request

I have urls paths with `name` in my `urls.py` file.

`urls.py`

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('home/', views.home, name="home_view"),
]
```

my `views.py`

```
def home(request):
    path_name = get_path_name(request.path)
    return HttpResponse(path_name)
```

Now, I need to get the path name, `"home_view"` in the HttpResponse.

How can I make my custom function, `get_path_name()` to return the `path_name` by taking `request.path` as argument?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `request.resolver_match.view_name` to get the `name` of current view.

```
def home(request):
    path_name = request.resolver_match.view_name
    return HttpResponse(path_name)
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
from django.urls import path
from . import views

app_name = 'polls'

urlpatterns = [path('', views.index, name='index')]

print(urlpatterns[0]) # Output: <URLPattern '' [name='index']>
print(f"name is: {urlpatterns[0].name}") # Output: name is: index
```

So the URL leads to `/`
And the name is `"index"`